# Locating Bounty UI on a question with an accepted answer

Tags: support, bounty

I accepted an answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177313/exif-or-other-meta-data-data-that-windows-displays-but-php-does-not/30178223) but I would really like to award a bounty to the user who answered for going way above and beyond to help.

I have been over the page several times now and I can't find the Start A Bounty UI anywhere nor the count-down to be able to start one (which should be done now).

Can anyone advise as to how I access this on a previously answered question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait two days from asking a question to start a bounty. From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> ## How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

You asked your question May 11th at 20:44 UTC, and it's now 19:44 UTC on May 13th. Give it another hour and you should be able to start your bounty just fine.

Comment: Thank you- I had made a note about when bounty would be available but had incorrectly specified the time.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh The UTC part can sometimes throw you off on the times. If you didn't know already, you can check what time it is UTC by opening the "Achievements" dropdown on the navigation bar. In the top right corner should be the current UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a bounty after the question has been [posted for 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

> **Which questions are eligible?**
>
> If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the following applies:
>
> - The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.
> - You already have three outstanding bounties. You can only have three open bounties at any one time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award at least one of the previous bounties first.
> - The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.
>
> You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

Comment: Thank you- I had made a note about when bounty would be available but had incorrectly specified the time.